# Running loop on all columns with pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pipe

I want to run a **for loop** with all columns starting from 1. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['X', 'Y'], 'A' : [1,2], 'B' : [3,4]})
for i in range(1, 3) :
    dat.iloc[:, i] = dat.iloc[:, i].astype(float)
```

While this is fine, I want to use `pipe` method to achieve the same in a concise way. Here the applied function is simple `astype`, however I should be able to use any custom function including `lambda`.

Is there any way to perform this?

Comment: `dat.iloc[:,1:3] = dat.iloc[:,1:3].astype(float)`?

Comment: Also `dat.iloc[:, 1:3] = dat.iloc[:, 1:3].apply(myfunc)` in the general case

Comment: @QuangHoang Please post solutions as answers, not comments.

Comment: an un-explained line of code isn't a full answer, [but it can be a helpful comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments). I think Quang Hoang knows how to use the site ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way without iloc. I don't think `pipe` is useful for this problem

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['X', 'Y'], 'A' : [1,2], 'B' : [3,4]})
cols = dat.columns[1:]
dat[cols] = dat[cols].apply(lambda v: v.astype(float))
dat
```

Comment: this is the same as, but slower than, the iloc method, and if you know you're going to convert all columns in a block to float, it's definitely best to call .astype on the dataframe rather than use apply with a lambda function.